# NSIS InstallOptionsEx Validate

Tags: nsis

Need some help with InstallOptionsEx Validation. In InstallOptions we use Flags=Notify and then we did somehting like this in the function

```
  ReadINIStr $0 "$PLUGINSDIR\test.ini" "Settings" "State"
  StrCmp $0 0 validate  ; Next button?
  StrCmp $0 2 supportx  ; "Install support for X"?
  StrCmp $0 9 clearbtn  ; "Clear" button?
  StrCmp $0 11 droplist ; "Show|Hide" drop-list?
  Abort ; Return to the page
```

But in InstallOptionsEx they say they did away with it in favor of the new method.

This is from the InstallOptionsEx Readme file:

```
 Step 5: Validate the Output 
If you want to validate the input on the page, for example, you want to check whether the user has filled in a textbox, use the leave function of the Page command and Abort when the validation has failed:
  Function ValidateCustom

    ReadINIStr $R0 "$PLUGINSDIR\test.ini" "Field 1" "State"
    StrCmp $0 "" 0 +3
      MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK "Please enter your name."
      Abort

  FunctionEnd

  Step 6: Return Value 
After you have called the DLL, InstallOptionsEx adds one string to the stack, with one of the following values:
success - The user has pressed the Next button
back - The user has pressed the Back button
cancel - The user has pressed the Cancel button
error - An error has occurred, the dialog cannot be displayed.
Usually, you don't need to check this value, but you still have to remove it from the stack (have a look at the example above).
You only have to check this value if you need something really special, such as doing something when the user pressed the Back button.
```

Can someone help me with figuring out new method? If you look at the code file below there is an old and new section and in the new section you will see what I am trying to do. Need help with the code.

Here is a ini file and code file:

ini file

```
[Settings]
NumFields=5

[Field 1]
Type=Label
Left=160
Right=235
Top=9
Bottom=18
Text="DropDown 1"
txtAlign=Center


[Field 2]
Type=DROPLIST
ListItems=Option 1a|Option 1b|Option 1c
State=
Flags=
Left=160
Right=235
Top=18
Bottom=25

[Field 3]
Type=Label
Left=240
Right=295
Top=9
Bottom=18
Text="DropDown 2"
txtAlign=Center


[Field 4]
Type=DROPLIST
ListItems=Option 2a|Option 2b|Option 2c
State=
Flags=
Left=240
Right=295
Top=18
Bottom=28

[Field 5]
Type=Button
Flags=NOTIFY
State=
Text="More Info"
Left=200
Right=250
Top=125
Bottom=140
txtAlign=Center
```

code file

```
!include WinVer.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include x64.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include MUI2.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include InstallOptions.nsh
!include Sections.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh

 !define MUI_HEADERIMAGE

  !define TEMP1 $R0 ;Temp variable

Page custom ShowCustom LeaveCustom ;Custom page. InstallOptions gets called in SetCustom.
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Function .onInit
  InitPluginsDir
  File /oname=$PLUGINSDIR\pagesetup.ini "pagesetup.ini"
FunctionEnd


Function ShowCustom
  InstallOptionsEx::initDialog "$PLUGINSDIR\pagesetup.ini"
  Pop $0
  InstallOptionsEx::show
  Pop $0
FunctionEnd


 #Old Method
 /*
Function LeaveCustom
  ReadINIStr $0 "$PLUGINSDIR\pagesetup.ini" "Settings" "State"
  StrCmp $0 0 validate  ; Next button?
  StrCmp $0 5 Infobtn ; 
  Abort ; Return to the page
Infobtn
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_USERICON|MB_TOPMOST "Infobtn Pressed"
Abort ; Return to the page

validate:
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_USERICON|MB_TOPMOST "Next Pressed"
    #Some Code to check if Field 2 and Field 4 have something selected
    Abort 
 FunctionEnd
*/

 #New Method
Function LeaveCustom
#Not sure correct code

 #If Back Btn Pressed goto backbtn
 #If Cancel Btn Pressed goto cancelbtn
 #If Next Btn Pressed goto nextbtn
 #If Info btn Press goto infobtn

 backbtn:
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_USERICON|MB_TOPMOST "Backbtn Pressed"
 Abort

 cancelbtn:
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_USERICON|MB_TOPMOST "Cancelbtn Pressed"
 Abort

 nextbtn:
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_USERICON|MB_TOPMOST "Nextbtn Pressed"
 Abort

 infobtn:
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_USERICON|MB_TOPMOST "Infobtn Pressed"
 Abort

 FunctionEnd

Section 

SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out and though I would post incase others need.

I had this:

```
Function ShowCustom
  InstallOptionsEx::initDialog "$PLUGINSDIR\pagesetup.ini"
  Pop $0
  InstallOptionsEx::show
  Pop $0
FunctionEnd
```

And it should have been this: (Ex should not have been there)

```
Function ShowCustom
  InstallOptions::initDialog "$PLUGINSDIR\pagesetup.ini"
  Pop $0
  InstallOptions::show
  Pop $0
FunctionEnd
```

Then just use the current for checking

```
  ReadINIStr $0 "$PLUGINSDIR\test.ini" "Settings" "State"
  StrCmp $0 0 validate  ; Next button?
  StrCmp $0 2 supportx  ; "Install support for X"?
  StrCmp $0 9 clearbtn  ; "Clear" button?
  StrCmp $0 11 droplist ; "Show|Hide" drop-list?
  Abort ; Return to the page
```